# Using gstreamer with Python OpenCV to capture stream, how set the first parameter of VideoCapture?

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

First of all I have Python 3 with the Gstreamer library in it.

`print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`

It shows Gstreamer with YES next to it.

Here is the shell command I typed into the pc terminal, which successfully calls the camera:

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! xvimagesink -ev`

and I will be using Python code to determine shapes, recognize objects, etc..

Here is my Python code:

```py
import cv2
 
# 创建GStreamer管道字符串
# gst_str = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! xvimagesink -ev"
# gst_str = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! appsink"
gst_str = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! ximagesi"

# 初始化VideoCapture对象
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gst_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
while True:
    # 从摄像头获取图像帧
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Cannot capture from camera. Exiting.")
        break
        
    # 在窗口上显示图像帧
    cv2.imshow("Camera", frame)
    
    # 按下'q'退出循环
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
 
# 关闭窗口和摄像头连接
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It can't get the cap object and then jumps out of the loop. How should I set gst_str?
In the terminal, gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0! The xvimagesink -ev 'command will execute successfully, but not in the python script, I think it must be that the gst_str variable is not set correctly, how should I set the gst_str variable?

In the terminal, gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0! The xvimagesink -ev 'command will execute successfully, but not in the python script, I think it must be that the gst_str variable is not set correctly, how should I set the gst_str variable?